# Highchart tooltip hover not working properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart that can have two points in the X Axis (with different Y values), but the highcharts tooltip doesn't work properly in this case, the jsfiddle is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/p5d1tzws/

Here's te code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Area chart with negative values'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [{
                    name: 'Point 1',
                    y: 2,
                    x: 1
                }, {
                    name: 'Point 2',
                    x: 1,
                    y: 4
                }, {
                    name: 'Point 3',
                    x: 2,
                    y: 5
                }, {
                    name: 'Point 4',
                    x: 2,
                    y: 8
                }, {
                    name: 'Point 5',
                    x: 3,
                    y: 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code below and see [highcharts documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.findNearestPointBy)

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
      findNearestPointBy: 'x', //or "xy" to both axis 
      marker: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  }
```